# Function pointer inside class point to that class's member function

Tags: c++

I am familiar with the function pointer to class member issue, which requires the signature to be `ClassName::*FuncPtr`, but I have this nuanced problem where I need the function pointer to be to a containing class member:

```
class F
{
public:
    class Container;
    typedef void (Container::*FuncPtr)();
    
    F(FuncPtr fp) : m_fp(fp) {}
    void Execute() { (*this.*m_fp)(); }
private:
    FuncPtr m_fp;
};

class Container
{
public:
    Container() : fps(&Container::Func) { }
    void Func() { }
private:
    F fps;
};
```

So, basically I want to create an object `Container`, which will send in its constructor a pointer to one of its member functions to the `F` object it contains, which should store that function pointer.

Comment: Side note: [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) could be your friend here. It can bind the member function to the correct instance. Otherwise `F` must be provided a `Container` instance to go along with `fp`. `std::function` can make `F` completely agnostic; it will allow `F` to handle any function Member, static member, free, and even a lambda expression) that has no parameters and returns nothing without `F` needing to know anything about the function and its source..

Comment: Thanks user4581301, I will take a look at std::function as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to move the forward declaration `class Container;` outside of `F`. Inside of `F`, it is declaring `F::Container`, which is a different type than `Container`.

Also, `(*this.*m_fp)()` (alternatively `(this->*m_fp)()`) won't work at all, as `m_fp` is expecting a `Container` object on the left side of `.*` (or `->*`), but `this` is pointing at an `F` object instead.  So `Container` will have to pass its `this` pointer to `F`'s constructor to be stored along with `m_fp`.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Container;

class F
{
public:
    typedef void (Container::*FuncPtr)();
    
    F(Container &c, FuncPtr fp) : m_c(c), m_fp(fp) {}
    void Execute() { (m_c.*m_fp)(); }
private:
    Container& m_c;
    FuncPtr m_fp;
};

class Container
{
public:
    Container() : fps(*this, &Container::Func) { }
    void Func() { ... }
private:
    F fps;
};
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/D93bcL)